# Erroneous getIntersection() results after canvas is zoomed or moved

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

I use the KineticJS getIntersection() function to dictate whether a click/tap is made on an element from one of a few layers in my canvas, and it works fine as long as I don't move the canvas or zoom in. Once I do either of those things, it seems like the hit graph gets messed up. Anyone dealt with anything like this before?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Sounds like you need to scale with a zoom and translate with a move

Comment: Can you create any fiddle?